# permission of knowing a directory empty or not

Tags: linux

When I tried to simulate the permission system under Linux, some strange things came about.

I created a directory 'main' by user 'normal', and created directory 'aha' which permission is 700 using root.

so the owner of 'main' is 'normal', if the permission is 755, I can delete 'aha' just using 'normal' user although its owner is root.

but when i put a file in 'aha', everything is changed. I can not remove 'aha' due to there's still a file in it.

so, my question is, since 'aha' is 700 by root, how can 'normal' know it's empty or not?

My further question is : what does read permission of a directory really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a UNIX directory as a drawer of index cards in the library catalog.

In order to know what books there are, you need read permission on the "drawer".  In order to create or remove new "books", you need write permissions (which give you ability to put new cards, or remove existing cards from the drawer). In order to "traverse" the directory to a lower level "sub-drawer", you need execute permission on the drawer itself.

If you already know that book /foo/bar/baz exists, you don't need read permissions on `/`, `/foo` or `/foo/bar`, but you do need execute permissions on all of them.

A given book could be referenced by multiple "cards" in the same or separate "drawer" (that's hard links).

A "card" can reference another card (that's symlinks). Symlinks could became "dangling" (if the other card is removed).

When a book is not referenced by any card in any of the drawers, it "evaporates" from the library.

> since 'aha' is 700 by root, how can 'normal' know it's empty or not

Well, one way is to try to remove it. If you succeed, it must have been empty. If it was not empty, "normal" can't find out anymore than that, since "normal" can't read the directory, and therefore can't find how many cards are in that "drawer", or what they are called.

Update:

> why do you need execute permissions to traverse a directory.

Because that's the definition of the eXecutable bit for directories. Since you can't reasonably execute a directory, that bit would be wasted otherwise. No, the `.` and `..` files have nothing to to do with the execute bit.

Comment: thx for explaining, 'Well, one way is to try to remove it. If you succeed, it must have been empty' this seems to be a loop definition.I mean i just don't understand why we can remove a empty directory instead of a non-empty one..

Comment: Even `root` can only ever use the [`rmdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html) system successfully on an empty directory.  (The `rm -r` command could mislead you here.)  If the directory is not empty, the `rmdir()` operation fails.  If the directory is empty, the permissions that control whether the directory can be removed are the permissions on the containing directory.  If the person executing the `rmdir()` can write in the containing directory, then they can remove the empty directory.

Comment: hi, one question, why do you need execute permissions to traverse a directory. I don't get it, is it something to do with the . & .. files?

Comment: so, there's a piece of implicit information which we can obtain by calling rmdir(), isn't it?

Comment: @ymfoi not sure to whom the last comment was directed but in answer to your original comment i think rmdir() provides a safe way to remove a 'folder' and simply fail where rm -r would just delete everything and ask you if you really wanted to remove each individual file

Answer (score 1):

very basically a file/dir permission of 700 is not seven hundred but actually

- owner = 7
- group = 0
- everyone = 0

the numbers pertain to a permission level

- 0 = no permission
- 1 = allow to execute  (run file or access directory)
- 2 = allow to write    (manipulate)
- 4 = allow to read     (see)

you add the permissions levels up to assign more then one permission for example

```
$ chmod 754 foo
```

gives full access to the owner (1+2+4), execute 'n' read to the group (1+4), and read to everyone (4) look at

- http://www.linuxclues.com/articles/16.htm
- http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html

for more info